# How can I create a facebook login page with firebase in flutter if "SignInWithFacebook" is not available anymore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm trying to have a facebook login page but everywhere I see they use signInWithFacebook, unfortunately it seems they've modified it and it's not available anymore, what should I do instead? Thanks for your help!

```
class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {


FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

bool isLogged = false;

Future<FirebaseUser> _loginWithFacebook() async {
 var facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
 var result = await 
  facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"]);

  debugPrint(result.status.toString());

if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
   FirebaseUser user = await _auth.????/

  }

}
```

Comment: [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_facebook_login/latest/) is a well-regarded library with a very similar API. Check the plugin docs or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50712086) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this method really  works, I could use it, but unfortunately it is not connected to the Firebase.

Comment: Ah, indeed. So the way I have seen this implemented is using Firebase's `signInWithCredential`, passing this method the access token that you receive from a successful flutter_facebook_login authorization flow. [firebase_auth source reference](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart#L233). The source code comment states "Asynchronously signs in to Firebase with the given 3rd-party credentials (e.g. a Facebook login Access Token..." -- maybe you will have some luck with it?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I could solve it with signInWithCredential(FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken:!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, I needed to have "signInWithCredential(FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken:))" instead of signInWithFacebook.I saw it is the same for Google sign in, where instead of using "FacebookAuthProvider" you need to use "GoogleAuthProvider"!